# How to acknowledge in a bulk?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMQ listener, from there i process the incoming data, collect them to a size of 7500 items and save them on Elasticsearch as a bulk (ElasticClient.IndexMany (data)). Using the bulk I get a much better performance and that is important for my application. After saving the data I know it was successful or not and I can acknowledge or reject them on RabbitMQ. The problem is that I get the next data from RabbitMQ only after responding the acknowledgement or rejection. So I cant bulk my data anymore.

Do you have any idea for a solution for that problem? How to get many items from RabbitMQ, process them and deliver the response (acknowledged or rejected) in a bulk back to RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a combination of [prefetch](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) and [multiple acknowledgement](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#consumer-acks-multiple-parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Luke. His answer give me the needful informations.
I changed at the Program.cs from

```
Model.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
```

to:

```
Model.BasicQos(0, NUMBER_OF_TIMESERIES_PER_BULK, false);
```

I add a listener:

```
    static void TimeSeriesBusinessComponentDeliverResponse(object sender, DeliverEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ListDeliverTagsAcknoledge.ForEach(tag => { Model.BasicAck((ulong)tag, false); });
        e.ListDeliverTagReject.ForEach(tag => { Model.BasicReject((ulong)tag, false); });
    }
```

After the number of NUMBER_OF_TIMESERIES_PER_BULK I save then to Elastic,
it looks like that:

```
        var responseSlimData = ElasticClientSlim.IndexMany(slimData);

        DeliverEventArgs dea = new DeliverEventArgs();
        if (responseSlimData.IsValid)
            dea.ListDeliverTagsAcknoledge = listDeliferyTags;
        else
            dea.ListDeliverTagReject = listDeliferyTags;
        OnDeliverResponse(dea);
        // .....

    public event EventHandler<DeliverEventArgs> DeliverResponse;
    protected virtual void OnDeliverResponse(DeliverEventArgs e)
    {
        DeliverResponse?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
```

And I add my EventArgs class

```
public class DeliverEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public DeliverEventArgs()
    {
        ListDeliverTagsAcknoledge = new List<ulong?>();
        ListDeliverTagReject = new List<ulong?>();
    }
    public List<ulong?> ListDeliverTagsAcknoledge { get; set; }
    public List<ulong?> ListDeliverTagReject { get; set; }
}
```